# Растягивание фона блока по ширине экрана из середины страницы

Tags: css, css3

Не уверен, что правильно сформировал вопрос в заголовке, поэтому прикрепил картинку. Хотелось узнать, как и кто работает с размещением блоков с фоном на всю ширину экрана из блока с контентом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Условно говоря, имеем такую структуру:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.middle {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.page-wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.full-wrapper {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: -1000px;
  margin-right: -1000px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="middle">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <div class="full-wrapper">
      <div class="middle">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Примером выше я активно пользуюсь, объяснять в нем особо нечего. Возможно кто-то предложит лучший вариант решения, так как у моего есть ряд недостатков. Кто и что думает про использование JS?

Написал скрипт для данного дела:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var winWidth = $(window).width();
  $('.full-wrapper').each(function() {
    var offset = $('.page-wrapper').offset();
    $(this).css({
      'width': winWidth,
      'left': -offset.left - 10
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.middle {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.full-wrapper {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrapper middle">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <div class="full-wrapper">
    <div class="middle">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: А вопрос какой?

Comment: Вопрос в том, кто какими способами данной подачи пользуется. Например, есть в WP Visual-composer который растягивает при помощи JS такие блоки из контента страницы. Хочется иметь простой и удобный вариант под рукой.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант подойдёт?

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.middle,
.full {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.middle {
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.full {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="full">
  <div class="middle">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="middle">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Я полагал, что этот вариант очевиден ввиду своей простоты. Вопрос заключается именно о вставке из содержимого страницы, не разбивая на группы.

Comment: Раз оба варианта не подходят, то считайте js'ом

Comment: Написал пример с JS. Можно ли его сократить или записать как-то иначе с учетом ресайза? Я планировал просто задублировать в `$(window).resize(function() { ... });`